# Ruby If Elsif Else block syntax

Tags: ruby, if-statement

What's wrong with this block?

```
if item.nil?
   found = true
elsif item[:name] == name && item[:category] == category
   found = true
else
   i++
end
```

When I do syntax checking, I get

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

but if I delete `end` then I get

```
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
i++
```

Ruby doesn't have a `++` operator. What you want is this:

```
i += 1
```

I believe the reason for that specific error is that Ruby is interpreting the second `+` as a unary `+` operator, i.e. the "positive number sign" (because it's the only thing that makes sense in that context), and so expects the next token to be a number<sup>†</sup>, e.g. (parentheses for clarity):

```
i + (+5)
```

...but the next token is `end`, ergo the syntax error.

<sup>†</sup>Or something else that [responds to the `+@` method](http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html).